# EWS Managed API: how to set From of email?

Tags: c#, ews-managed-api

I'm using EWS Managed API to sending email. Account "**account**@domain.com" have permissions "Send as" to  use "**sender**@domain.com" mailbox to send messages (from Outlook, it's work fine).

But I try from code - it's not work, in mail i'm read in the field "From" "**account**@domain.com".

```
....
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Body = txtMessage;
message.Subject = txtSubject;
message.From = txtFrom;
....
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

How to make sending mail on behalf of another user? :)

Answer (score 6):

It's been a while since I fiddled with the same thing, and I concluded that it isn't possible, in spite of having "Send as" rights.

Impersonation is the only way to go with EWS, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633680%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx):

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.AutodiscoverUrl("app@domain.com");

// impersonate user e.g. by specifying an SMTP address:
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(
    ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "user@domain.com");
```

If impersonation isn't enabled, you'll have to supply the credentials of the user on behalf of whom you want to act. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ff597939%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com");
```

Alternatively you can simply specify a [reply-to address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.replyto%28v=exchg.80%29).

```
EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage(service);
mail.ReplyTo.Add("user@email.com");
```

However, "Send as" rights *do* apply when sending mail using System.Net.Mail, which in many cases will do just fine when just sending e-mails. There are [tons of examples](http://www.google.dk/#q=send+mail+system.net.mail) illustrating [how to do this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx).

```
// create new e-mail
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("user@domain.com");
mail.To.Add(new MailAdress("recipient@somewhere.com"));
message.Subject = "Subject of e-mail";
message.Body = "Content of e-mail";

// send through SMTP server as specified in the config file
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: mail.ReplyTo will not work, there is no setter on this.
public EmailAddressCollection ReplyTo { get; }

Comment: Right, it's a collection. So you'll need to do `mail.ReplyTo.Add("user@email.com")` - I'll fix the example above.

Comment: Using Impersonation I get an error on mail.send. - The primary SMTP address must be specified when referencing a mailbox

Comment: @markthewizard1234 a quick search on Google, and I found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/c7fa0260-5399-4ec7-ba46-a5e23a0b4b6d/exchange-managed-api-user-with-multiple-mailboxes?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment - As the error indicates, you must use the primary SMTP address when specifying the mailbox you want to access, not a proxy/secondary address or alias.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use the `Sender` property so the your code should look like:

```
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Body = txtMessage;
message.Subject = txtSubject;
message.Sender= txtFrom;
....
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Comment: No this doesn't appear to work.  I've tried setting sender, sender.name and sender.Address and even though they get set, the email still comes from the account specified in your service setup.